# Remove stacktraces from an emit pragma

Tags: macros, nim-lang

How do I create emit macros that don't add a stacktrace?

```
import macros

macro emitWithoutStacktrace(): stmt = 
  result = newStmtList()
  result.add quote do:
    {.push stacktrace: off.}
  result.add(newNimNode(nnkPragma).add(newNimNode(nnkExprColonExpr).add(newIdentNode("emit"), newStrLitNode("foobar"))))
  result.add quote do:
    {.pop stacktrace: off.}

proc main = 
  emitWithoutStacktrace()

main()
```

Produces

```
N_NIMCALL(void, main_104042)(void) {
    nimfr("main", "test.nim")
    nimln(7, "test.nim");
    foobar
    popFrame();
}
```

Where I would prefer

```
N_NIMCALL(void, main_104042)(void) {
    foobar
    popFrame();
}
```

Without any additional compiler arguments like `--stacktrace: off`.

Comment: `{.push linedir: off.}` should work, but it doesn't. Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: @user60561, No, linedir doesn't work. Still has `nimln` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the same happens with this code:

```
proc main =
  {.push stacktrace: off.}
  echo "hi"
  {.pop.}

main()
```

Instead you need to surround the entire proc with the push/pop:

```
{.push stacktrace: off.}
proc main =
  echo "hi"
{.pop.}

main()
```

I just noticed this yesterday when trying to do `{.push rangechecks: on.}`.